# In EmberJS how can you use transition data in a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-octane

I am getting the `transition` data in the route js file like so:

```
beforeModel(transition) { console.log(transition)  }
```

And I want to use it in a function in my controller like this:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default class ListingsController extends Controller {

    get pageTitle() {
        if (this.transition.targetName == 'foo') {
        return 'page title';

        }
      }

}
```

And then I want to display the result like this:

```
<h1>{{this.pageTitle}}</h1>
```

I cannot find a way to pass the `transition` data from the route to the controller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

While you *technically* can leverage the `beforeModel` to get the controller via `this.controllerFor` as @KathirMagaesh suggests, I wouldn't actually advocate for this solution. It's definitely not the *normal* or *expected* Ember pattern. Furthermore, if you look at the [transition api](http://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/Transition), there is no reference to `transition.targetName`. If this works, this is private api and thus brittle.

If you need to change a property based on the current route, you should be using the [public router service](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService) which provides some useful properties for this very purpose!

For example, in your controller you could have a computed property that leverages the router service to determine what the page title should be

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';

// this injects the router service into our component via Ember's DI framework
router: inject(),
export default Controller.extend({
  pageTitle: computed('router.currentRouteName', function(){
     let currentRoute = this.router.currentRouteName;
     if(currentRoute === 'foo'){
        return 'page title';
     } 
     // do other stuff for other routes. 
  })
})
```

This leverages [currentRouteName](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRoute?anchor=currentRouteName) which is the period separated name like `foo.bar`. You can also also access the url via [currentURL](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRoute?anchor=currentURL) which would be `/foo/bar`

PS. Since I haven't used ES6 classes yet, I've provided the old style ember solution. You'll probably need to use the `@computed` decorator or `@tracked` where I'm using the `computed` function. I only know about the Octane ember style from RFCs and [awesome blog posts](https://www.pzuraq.com/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-1-native-classes/) but am not up to date with what's landed.

PPS. If you're on old ember, the current route name / URL properties are available on the application controller.

Comment: Thank you this is definitely a better way of doing it. I am using Octane as much as I can in this project. One thing I can't get around is injecting the router. I followed the Octane way of implementation and it works great within a component but throws an error inside a controller. `'types' can only be used in a .ts file.`

Comment: @UXCODA does this error present itself simply by injecting the router into a controller?

Comment: Yes, quite odd really. I would expect the controller to work similar to a component.

Comment: You may have the best luck understanding what the problem is there in the [ember discord](https://discordapp.com/invite/emberjs)

Comment: Thanks for the better solution @mistahenry

Answer (score 2):

In the **beforeModel** hook use

> this.controllerFor(currentrRouteName).set('transition', transition);

This will set transition property in **controller of the current router**.

For more on [controllerFor()](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=controllerFor)